# How to get $(this) in nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I want to display image after it loaded completely to achieve this thing, I try to wrote some code its getting `data-src` from image and adding it in to new Image object, after loaded that object, it should replace that `image src` with `object src` but there a problem, in nested function `$(this)` is not working  it only getting last image here is the code...

```
$('li img').each(function(){
timg = $(this);
var k = new Image();
k.src = $(timg).data('src');
$(k).load(function(){
    console.log (k.src);
    $(timg).attr('src', k.src);
    //timg [$(This)] is not working;
});
});
```

Comment: what is not working? show more code. `$(This)` is incorrect syntax and within `load` callback `this` will be same as `k`

Comment: @charlietfl: _nested function only getting last image_

Comment: @charlietfl timg is global, so it reassign on every loop iteration, and when load function fire - it catch last timg value

Comment: Your whole problem is simply not using `var timg`

Comment: @charlietfl your are right its working with var timg and bind() too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `timg` already jQuery obj, so you don't need any conversion. Also you use global var `timg` so it changed in each loop iteration, so just use local.

```
$('li img').each(function(){
    var timg = $(this);
    var k = new Image();
    k.src = timg.data('src');
    $(k).load(function(){
        console.log (k.src);
        timg.attr('src', k.src);
    });
});
```

Comment: if `op` is used `$(timg)` then also fine... this would not solution

Comment: @Girish, methinks, _op_ use global var `timg`, instead local, in my sample i use local

Answer (score 1):

Use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to explicit tell your neastead function who you want to be its `this` variable:

```
$('li img').each(function(){
    var k = new Image();
    k.src = $(this).data('src');
    $(k).load(function(){
        console.log (k.src);
        $(this).attr('src', k.src);
        console.log(this); // Shall work now
    }.bind(this));
});
```

In more details:

```
// First case
function MyTest() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(this); // will log [object Window]
    });
}
// Second case
function MyTest() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(this); // will log "anything"
    }.bind("anything"));
}
// Another case
function MyTest() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(this); // will log [object Object] (MyTest)
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Look this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0p1rob1q/)

Comment: in your another case `will log [object Object] (MyTest)` only if call `new MyTest()` is call `MyTest()` then `will log [object Window]`